# Find a match word and printing letters by their sides

Tags: python, regex, text

I am trying to find a word on a string, match it with a query word, and then print them with some of their neighboring letters, like this:

```
input =  aaxxYYxxaa
match = YY
requested_output = xxYYxx
```

So far I have tried with the Regex module, but I cannot go beyond the ‘match’ part:

```
import re
teststring = "aaxxYYxxaa"
word = re.findall (r"YY", teststring)
print(word)
```

output = YY

What could I do here to print the letters on each end of the ‘YY’ word?.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r".{0,2}YY.{0,2}", teststring)` if you want to match any 0 to 2 chars before and after the `YY` value.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you want to match any 0 to 2 chars before and after the `YY` value. Add `.{0,2}` on both sides of the pattern:

```
re.findall(r".{0,2}YY.{0,2}", teststring)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/prqBvz/2) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/okpKyt):

```
import re
teststring = "aaxxYYxxaa"
word = re.findall (r".{0,2}YY.{0,2}", teststring)
print(word) # => ['xxYYxx']
```

Answer (score 0):

You would write your regex in a way, that it matches arbitrary characters before and after you known search term.

`.` matches any character 
`{m,n}` repeats at least m times and at most n times

so to match `xxYYxx` you would say     `.{2,2}YY.{2,2}`